# play <audio></audio> file in django template

Tags: django, audio, media

I've been struggling with this for so long that I'm bordering depression.

I have a model called "Song" that looks like this.

```
from django.db import models

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    songfile = models.FileField()
    duration = models.FloatField()
    isPlaying = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

When you upload an mp3 file from the index page, it creates an instance of this model and stores the file in myapp/songdir/ using this view:

```
def home(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            song_title = request.POST.items()[1][1]
            song_address = 'upnplay/songdir/' + song_title + '.mp3'
            with open(song_address, 'wb+' ) as destination:
                for chunk in request.FILES['file'].chunks():
                    destination.write(chunk)
                audio = MP3(song_address)
                c = Song(title = song_title, songfile = song_address, duration = audio.info.length)
                c.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    c = {'form': form}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Then I have a template called "choosesong" that displays a list of songs that I get from the model instances saved:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}


{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    {% for song in playlist %}
        <a href="playlist/{{song.title}}/"><h3>{{song.title}} -- {{song.duration}}</h3></a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
{% block form %}{% endblock %}
```

When I click on one of this links, I want a new template to be rendered, with a  element that plays the song whose name I clicked. The template that I render is this one:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class='row'>
    {{link}}
    <audio controls>
        <source src="../../{{ link }}" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

And the view I use to deliver it is the following:

```
def playAudioFile(request, songtitle):
    name = urllib.unquote(songtitle)
    song = get_object_or_404(Song, title=name )
    return render(request, 'playlist.html', {'link': song.songfile })
```

For some reason I can't get it to play the song inside the audio element and I don't know what else to try.

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: 1. Can you write, by hand, the correct HTML that will play this song? 2. Does Django generate the same HTML?

Comment: And what is responsible for serving the file at that link? What have you configured to do so?

Comment: well, I thought that the audio's src attribute would point at the address where the file lives, and so the audio element would know which file to play.

There must be a flaw in my reasoning, otherwise it would work. Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 16):

You should add MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL configuration. It will be easy to handle things. Here is the solution to your problem.

In settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"songdir")
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

Also in settings.py add 
    'django.template.context_processors.media',
in the TEMPLATES option's context_processors.

In project/urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Then you can simply use:

```
{{link.url}}
```

instead of hardcoding it in your template file.

Comment: Actually I haven't even configured that, I thought I could just point at the folder.

I guess that what you mean is that I should set:

MEDIA_ROOT = 'upnplay/songdir'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' (Or whatever name)

And then create a view that responds to /media/songname

Is this what you mean? Did I leave something out?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

It worked like magic. I didn't have to include the context processor though because c9 (the IDE where I program) uses the default settings, in which this processor is included.

Also 'chrome dev tools' helped me to figure out that I was duplicating the path to the file.

Comment: If that helped you. Please choose it as answer.

Comment: I used this to add `<a>media/MY_AUDIO_FILE</a>` to my blog-like localhost page.