# Using Django static() to generate audio files' URLs in production

Tags: django

I'm trying to get my Django app to play audio files (supposedly) uploaded by users via a form. Said files are tied to a model :

```
# models.py
class Doc(models.Model):
    # ...
    tape = models.FileField()
```

The uploading and saving parts are working fine, and the files are stored where they should be :

```
- djangoproject
 |
 - docapp
  |
  - media <- here
```

So, in order to get where I want, I added these two lines to the settings.py file `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'docapp/media/')` and `MEDIA_URL = 'docapp/media/'`.

I hoped to be able to link to the audio files thus:

```
# templates/docapp/index.html
...
<audio src='{{ doc.tape.url }}' controls></audio>
```

Unfortunately, this wasn't working because the link generated by `doc.tap.url` (http://localhost/docapp/media/filename.aac) was returning a 404 error.

After a lot of googling I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670075/2372954), which I happily copy-pasted into my app ... and it worked. This is the code in question :

```
# urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The problem is that I'm not comfortable with inserting code in my apps that I don't understand. I did some research about the `static()` function and all I could get [is this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#static) :

> Helper function to return a URL pattern for serving files in **debug mode**

Does this mean that the `static` function should not be used in production? If so, **what should I be using in production**? And what *exactly* does it do?

**EDIT** To be clear, the generated URL after injecting the solution is the **same** as the one generated without it. Yet, it only works when the `static()` function is present.

**EDIT 2** I forgot to mention that the 404 errors persisted even after I `chmod`ed the media folder to allow `other`s to read-access it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should copy paste the docs as an answer. For example this page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development and this section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: And user uploaded content https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: @allcaps: thanks, that was really helpful to understand what was going on. Are there any links on how should I be doing instead?

Comment: You shouldn't do anything instead. No errors no problem. The docs write about development server and serving static files AND that it is for development only. In a production environment you configure your server to serve the files from the media folder. That's all. Try to configure media files and access the file via it's url. If it works, try the `{{ doc.tape.url }}` template tag.

Comment: Your `{{ doc.tap.url }}` should read `{{ doc.tape.url }}`

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it now! So, the 'only' purpose of the `static()` function is to avoid configuring the (dev) server. And that's why I need it here. In production, however, my code would work as-is -- I have just to configure the server. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, in your development environment your media may live in `/media/` route and directory. While on production it may be something like `media.example.com`. Running Django with the settings for that environment will change all media domains and paths to their correct locations. You may split settings file into a settings file for each environment (production, acceptance, development). Like https://github.com/twoscoops/two-scoops-of-django-1.8/blob/2a4d42474e320203e4d41410b6c5895b93e58b97/code/chapter_05_example_1.txt of course import from a base settings.py to keep it DRY.

Comment: Thank you so much dear stranger from the internet. Would you please put all of they in an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: If you don't need a CDN you could look into dj-static: https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do anything. No errors no problem. The docs write about [development server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) and [serving static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) AND that it is for development only. In a production environment you configure your server (Apache, NGNIX or third party like S3) to serve the files. That's all.

Try to configure media files and access the file via it's url. If it works, try the {{ doc.tape.url }} template tag.

In your development environment your media may live in `/media/` (route and directory). While on production it may be something like `media.example.com`. Running Django with the settings for that environment will change all static/media domains and paths to their correct locations.

You may split settings file into a settings file for each environment (production, acceptance, development). Like this:

```
project/
    settings/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        local.py
        staging.py
        test.py
        production.py
```

You can run your project with a specific env: `./manage.py runserver --settings=project.settings.development`. Do not repeat yourself and put development specific settings in `development.py` and `from base import *` so that `base.py` contains the default settings.

This project and settings layout is taken from the book Two Scoops of Django. It is just an example. Adjust to your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `django.conf.urls.static.static` is only for development and not for production.  For production, you should just need to configure your `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings and have your webserver serve the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory in the `MEDIA_URL` path.

Comment: Thanks! As you can see from the details above, I've already done that. I even tried with `chmod`ing the media folder. To no avail. Is there anything wrong with that I did?

Comment: @ahmed Where is it not working?  In production?  Are you using `django.conf.urls.static.static` in production?  Assuming you have `DEBUG=False` in production, which you should have, `django.conf.urls.static.static` will not work.  For production, you need to have your webserver serve the media files, and not Django.

Answer (score 0):

Basically adding that in the URL `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` will make the media files in the URL existing. Try removing that and visit your media file in the URL and you will receive a `404 not found`. It's very similar to the concept that you are inserting a `view` for rendering the media `files`

Comment: Yep, I've already tried that to see if that's really what made app work as intended. Can you please guide to how should be doing instead? Thanks!