# Displaying Audio/Video in Python Django Website

Tags: python, django

I am building a blog website where I can upload audio/video files to the database and then run a for loop to output the files in HTML audio/video tags. I have succeeded in saving the files to the database and also output them on the website but for some reason I can't get them to play.

I am still pretty new to Python/Django and I would appreciate it if anybody can help me figure this one out. Thanks in anticipation

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Track(models.Model):
   track_title         = models.CharField(max_length=250)   
   track               = models.FileField(upload_to='album/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.track_title
```

Here is my index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for track in tracks %}
<figure>
    <figcaption>Audio</figcaption>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{ track.track.url }}" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>       
</figure>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Track

def songView(request):
    tracks      = Track.objects.all()
    context = {
        'tracks':tracks
    }

  return render(request, 'album/index.html', context)
```

And my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'album'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.songView, name='song'),
]
```

Comment: This might be useful as you might have missed media url settings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670075/5353906

Comment: Thanks, I got it!